# Display:block; not working for fully clickable button

Tags: css, animation, button, hover, clickable

I'm trying to make my buttons fully clickable, but I'm missing something, I think my formatting is wrong or something. I think I have all the pieces. Some potential complications include the fact that it is animated.

http://jsfiddle.net/4mHTa/49/

```
#aboutme:a {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```

Greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little typo's fault, no need for that colon after #aboutme

```
#aboutme a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as mention by @pimmey there was typo's fault

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/4mHTa/52/)

```
#aboutme a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height:100px; /** align text vertically **/
    text-align:center; /** horizontally **/
}
```